# iPhone 4s text messages still appear in iPhone search results after being deleted

Tags: iphone

I have deleted a number of text messages on my iPhone. But, when I scroll to the right and to do an iPhone search, the deleted texts still appear in the search results.

How can I get rid of them?

Comment: also if you switch of spotlight that seems to work but there still going to be there

Answer (score 1):

The messages are still stored in a cache database, with a field "removed yes" or "removed no", speaking in easy terms.
You can get rid of these, if you really have to by syncing your phone with iTunes.

If that doesn't fix your issue you can create a back-up and restore that backup.
Restoring should clean the cache databases and making a back-up first makes sure you get exact the same version back as you had previously.

However, I don't know if you use spotlight often -> I just disabled many results from appearing in Spotlight.

Settings -> General -> Spotlight

Comment: back up restoring never worked so i re started factory settings then backed up.....  now i will do a text and delete then restore from back up and see if that gets rid watch out watch out   thank you for the reply

Comment: @user67450 Did you just sync with iTunes, didn't that solve it?

Comment: you mean open the iTunes and just sync tab on the bottom right

Comment: yes that seems to work i will tray a few more time to see if it has worked thanks

Comment: Robuust that worked once but won't do it again ?????

Comment: @user67450 It should work every time, not only once. That wouldn't make sense.

Comment: i know it's a pain and it's really annoying

Comment: it worked again but tried another email to see but not again i think it takes time to get off the phone

Answer (score -5):

Delete cookies and browser history after deleting the text.

Comment: How does this solve the problem for **local** text messages?

Comment: How do I give a correct answer and yet I get to minuses on my post?

Comment: @Jcocchi your "answer" has nothing to do with the question. This isn't about safari or cookies.